# How to modify the compilation line for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to compile a program with the following compilation line

```
cl /LD /DKXVER=3 mymoving.c mymoving.def q.lib
```

I keep getting all sorts of errors.

How can I add those flags to Visual Studio?

UPDATE:

main.cpp

```
#include "k.h"   

#define KXVER 3

#ifdef __cplusplus                                                    
extern "C" {
#endif

static K calc(K x, K y, K z) {                                                
        if (x->t != -KJ || y->t != -KJ) {                                           
            //const char* a = "type";
            //return krr(a);   
            return ki(5);
        }   
        else {
            switch (z->s[0]) {                                                   
            case 's': return kj(x->j + y->j);
            case 'd': return kj(x->j - y->j);
            case 'm': return kj(x->j*y->j);
            case 'D': return kj(x->j / y->j);
            default: return ki(5);
            }
        }
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbx2S.jpg)

Other steps: 
Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols > Check Microsoft Symbol Servers

Right Click solution > Properties > C/C++ > Command Line > Added /DKXVER=3 /LD in the Additional Options

Right Click solution > Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories > Added the Include directory containing k.h

Right Click solution > Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories > Added the x86 directory where q.lib is.

I don't know where to add the `.def` file.

The Error I get at the moment is

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cppkdbtut1att2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
1>Done building project "cppkdbtut1att2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Which I know it comes from the fact that I don't have `int main()`, but It should compile fine and return a .dll which I can load from q.

Comment: In the compiler, linker properties of the project. That's covered in the documentation since at least 1996 (first time I used VS). Most parameters appear as settings anyway, eg included libraries, headers etc.

Comment: In any case, VS will launch the same command line. Why not use what you already have?

Comment: Docs for VS 2017 are here : [Compiler Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options)

Comment: Are you trying to extend KDB following [this example](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/compile-load-c-dll)? DId you encounter a problem? If you used the wrong path, or tried to run `cl.exe` without initializing the development environment or worse, using the *wrong* batch file for it you'll get errors. What did you try, what errors did you get?

Comment: I know how to do it from the command line. I just need to compile it using the visual studio and I do not know what needs to be modified and where in order to make it work.

Comment: I posted the link to the docs `/LD` is just the DLL target, it's a drop-down. `mymoving.c` is the file or files in your project. `def` and `lib` are included libraries.  You'll find that in the `Compiler Options` page or tutorials for creating DLL projects

Comment: Check [Walkthrough: Create and use your own Dynamic Link Library (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp)

Comment: I followed the tutorial. My question is where can I include external libraries necessary in the compilation. I added them at the moment in the `Linker`, but not sure if that's where they supposed to go